# Telegram Bot - Check if a token is real in Python using telepot

Tags: python, token, telegram, telegram-bot, telepot

I want to check if the token of a Telegram bot is real.

I tried this:

```
try:
    bot = telepot.Bot(token)
except:
    pprint("Il token inserito non è valido! Riavvia il programma e inserisci un altro token!")
    ftok = open('C:/Limitatibot/token.txt','w')
    ftok.write('')
    ftok.close()
    pprint('Premere un tasto per continuare...')
    input()
    quit()
```

But it didn't work :C. How could it be solved?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. Explain what did not work for example and use English.